# Normalisation of Bessel functions

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

[image]

I've done the integration by parts and obtained

$$ \frac{-1}{\alpha^2} \int z^2 J J'$$

but I have no idea how to use Bessel's equation to simplify this as it only appears to get far more complicated.

Comment: You have obtained something, but reading this, there is no equality sign. The reader has no idea what you claim this to be equal to.

Answer (score 3):

Call the integral under inspection for $I$, and let all $J=J_n$. The substitution implies that we are bound to show that
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\int_0^\alpha z(J(z))^2\,dz=\frac{1}{2}(J'(\alpha))^2.
$$
I think it is more intuitive to start the work from the differential equation. First, we have the Bessel equation
$$
z^2J''+zJ'+(z^2-n^2)J=0,
$$
which can be written
$$
z(zJ')'=(n^2-z^2)J.
$$
Now multiply by $2J'$ to get
$$
2(zJ')'zJ'=(n^2-z^2)2JJ',
$$
or
$$
((zJ')^2)'=(n^2-z^2)(J^2)'
$$
Integrating from $0$ to $\alpha$, and then by parts, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha^2(J'(\alpha))^2&=\int (n^2-z^2)(J^2)'\,dz\\
&=\bigl[(n^2-z^2)(J(z))^2\bigr]_0^{\alpha}+2\int_0^\alpha z(J(z))^2\,dz\\
&=2\int_0^\alpha z(J(z))^2\,dz
\end{aligned}
$$
and we are done. Note that in the last step, we use that $(n^2-0^2)=0$ if $n=0$ and that $J_n(0)=0$ if $n>0$.